# array obj property is undefined in class constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

I am passing an array of objects (of which one of the properties is also an array) to a class constructor like this:

```
    this.timelapse = new timelapse(this.tlitems);
```

The class:

```
export class timelapse {
    items: timelapseitem[];
    meantime: number;

    constructor(i: timelapseitem[]) {
        this.items = i;
        console.log(i[0]);
        console.log(i[0].events);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

the second log (or any operation that tries to access the array property) is always `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

`this.tlitems` is an object reference.

In this object, `events` is a reference to an array.

You then apply this object to your class property : they have the same memory reference.

This means that **if you update the first object anywhere in your code, the class proeprty will be updated too**.

This is probably what's happening to you.

Also, remember that the console logs at a given time and doesn't update itself.

To avoid this kind of issue, you can try to find what updates your events, or you can duplicate your memory reference :

```
constructor(i: timelapseitem[]) {
    this.items = [...i];
    console.log(i[0]);
    console.log(i[0].events);
}
```

Comment: you mean that the issue is caused by shallow copying the obj?

i tried the spread operator and `this.items = Object.assign({}, i);` with no luck.

Comment: Well I rather mean the lack of it. Without a [mcve], the only issue I can see there is the fact that the arrays share the same memory reference, and I then assume that somewhere in your code, you update that reference (without changing it).

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
 this.timelapse = new timelapse(...this.tlitems);
```

"..." will create a copy of your object and send it by value not by reference.